# React Native. Mechanism for turning on/off console logs in one place

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-native, console.log

I have many **console.log** in my code. 
As we know those logs slow down app a lot, so at the end of development I need to delete all of them, but of course I don't remember all the places where I have it. How can I use some wrapper for console.log which I can use, so that I could turn on or turn off all the console logs in one place? If my approach is not very good, advise me some libraries, tools, ways of doing what I need...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in the following two ways:

```
if(!__DEV__) {
  console = {};
  console.log = () => {};
  console.error = () => {};
}
```

a better approach would be to use babel plugin transform-remove-console by
creating *.babelrc* file, and setting up babel transpiler.

example setup:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements

Answer (score 1):

Use this: https://github.com/babel/minify/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console

or you can creat a function in utils like this:

```
export const showLog = (tag, log) => {
  console.log(tag + ' : ' + log);
};
```

and use showLog anywhere in your project:

```
import { showLog } from '../utils/utils';

showLog('VideoPlayer', response)
```

Answer (score -1):

At the end, I've chosen the method described here - https://levelup.gitconnected.com/step-up-your-console-messaging-game-in-your-react-app-42eee17659ec
I like it best of all.

**Upd**: As Chmac mentioned (thanks), the link is dead. Archive link [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180212120119if_/https://levelup.gitconnected.com/step-up-your-console-messaging-game-in-your-react-app-42eee17659ec)

Comment: This is a dead link, the original [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20180212120119if_/https://levelup.gitconnected.com/step-up-your-console-messaging-game-in-your-react-app-42eee17659ec) on the wayback machine says to use the `debug` module instead, in **react apps**. Not so relevant for **react-native**.